# gtk : combo of pictures in a treeview

Tags: haskell, combobox, treeview, gtk, gtk2hs

I'm trying to make a combo box of pictures (as bellow) inside a treeview cell to make a selection.

[image]

I tried to use a `cellRendererComboNew` to render the combo but the options to fill the combobox `cellComboTextModel :=` work only for `String` and I can't render pictures.

I tried to use a `cellRendererPixbufNew`. It render images but I can't perform a selection on it.

What is the correct approach to make that?

An example in Haskell, Python, or in any language would be very helpfull.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

In PyGobject I came up with this solution. The example is fully functional but requires 2 png files in the same directory. I used two pngs with 100 x 20 pixel format.

The previous example used Gtk.ComboBox.new_with_model_and_entry() and I was missing the set_entry_text_colum() function that has to go with such kind of combobox.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GdkPixbuf

class ComboBoxWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="ComboBox Pixbuf Example")

        self.set_border_width(10)

        store = Gtk.ListStore(str, GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf)
        solid_line = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file("solid_line.png")
        store.append(["1", solid_line])
        dashed_line = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file("dashed_line.png")
        store.append(["2", dashed_line])

        vbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=6)

        combo = Gtk.ComboBox.new_with_model(store)
        rend_int = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        rend_pixbuf = Gtk.CellRendererPixbuf()
        combo.pack_start(rend_int, False)
        combo.add_attribute(rend_int, "text", 0)
        combo.pack_start(rend_pixbuf, True)
        combo.add_attribute(rend_pixbuf, "pixbuf", 1)
        combo.connect("changed", self.on_combo_changed)

        vbox.pack_start(combo, False, False, 0)

        self.add(vbox)

    def on_combo_changed(self, combo):
        tree_iter = combo.get_active_iter()
        if tree_iter != None:
            model = combo.get_model()
            row = model[tree_iter][0]
            print("Selected row {0}".format(row))

win = ComboBoxWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

[image]

Similar question:

- [Show icon or color in Gtk TreeView tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745585/show-icon-or-color-in-gtk-treeview-tree)

Source:

- http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/combobox.html

Comment: It works fine for **individual ComboBox** but not for a **combobox in a treeview**. Haskell code for individual combobox is in this post [http://stackoverflow.com/q/28258030/3595992].

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution in Haskell:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.String
import Graphics.UI.Gtk
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Data.Maybe
import qualified Graphics.UI.Gtk.Gdk.Pixbuf as Pixbuf
import Control.Monad

colorsRawL = [(0,0,0),(254,26,89),(255,0,0),(0,255,0),(0,0,255),(255,255,0),(0,255,255),(255,0,255),(192,192,192),(128,128,128),(128,0,0),(128,128,0),(0,128,0),(128,0,128),(0,128,128),(0,0,128)]
manufacturers = [("Sony"::String), ("LG"::String), ("Panasonic"::String), ("Toshiba"::String), ("Nokia"::String), ("Samsung"::String)]

data ListElement = ListElement { name :: String   ,   selected::Pixbuf  }

getManufacturers::IO[ListElement]
getManufacturers = mapM (\x -> do 
                             pbn <- Pixbuf.pixbufNew ColorspaceRgb False 8 16 16
                             Pixbuf.pixbufFill pbn 255 255 255 1 
                             let el = ListElement x pbn
                             return el                            
                           ) manufacturers
     
pixBufListS::IO [(String,Pixbuf)]
pixBufListS =   mapM (\(r,g,b)-> do 
                             pbn <- Pixbuf.pixbufNew ColorspaceRgb False 8 16 16
                             Pixbuf.pixbufFill pbn r g b 1 
                             let name::String = ("Color ("++(show r)++" "++(show g)++" "++(show b)++  ")")                             
                             return (name,pbn)                            
                           ) colorsRawL

getMap::IO (Map.Map String Pixbuf)
getMap = do
    list <- pixBufListS
    let mp = Map.fromList list
    return mp

main :: IO ()   
main = do    
    initGUI
    window  <- windowNew
    fixed <- fixedNew
    
    pixList <-pixBufListS

    manus <- getManufacturers
    lststoreManus::(ListStore ListElement) <- listStoreNew manus

    treeview <- treeViewNew
    treeViewSetModel treeview lststoreManus
    treeViewSetHeadersVisible treeview True

    colName <- treeViewColumnNew
    imgCol <- treeViewColumnNew
    colCombo <- treeViewColumnNew
    treeViewColumnSetTitle imgCol ("Image column"::T.Text  )
    treeViewColumnSetTitle colName ("String column"::T.Text  )
    treeViewColumnSetTitle colCombo ("Combo"::T.Text  )

    iconRenderer <- cellRendererPixbufNew
    renderer1 <- cellRendererTextNew
    comboRenderer <- cellRendererComboNew

    cellLayoutPackStart imgCol iconRenderer True
    cellLayoutPackStart colName renderer1 True
    cellLayoutPackStart colCombo comboRenderer True
    
    cellLayoutSetAttributes imgCol iconRenderer lststoreManus $  (\ListElement { selected = t } -> [cellPixbuf := t])
    cellLayoutSetAttributes colName renderer1 lststoreManus $ \row -> [ cellText := name row ]

    cellLayoutSetAttributeFunc colCombo comboRenderer lststoreManus $ 
        (\iter -> do (tmodel, colid) <- comboTextModel 
                     (ListElement a b) <- treeModelGetRow lststoreManus iter
                     set comboRenderer [ cellVisible        := True
                                       , cellComboTextModel := (tmodel, colid)
                                       , cellTextEditable   := True
                                       , cellComboHasEntry  := False
                                       , cellText           := ("Choose pixbuf"::String)])  

    treeViewAppendColumn treeview colName
    treeViewAppendColumn treeview imgCol
    treeViewAppendColumn treeview colCombo

    _ <- on comboRenderer editingStarted $ \widget treepath -> do
     case treepath of
      [k] -> do       
        let comboPix::ComboBox = castToComboBox widget
        
        lststorerep::(ListStore (String,Pixbuf)) <- listStoreNew pixList
        customStoreSetColumn lststorerep (makeColumnIdString 0) fst
        customStoreSetColumn lststorerep (makeColumnIdPixbuf 1) snd
      
        comboBoxSetModel comboPix (Just lststorerep)
        rendertxt <- cellRendererTextNew
        renderpic <- cellRendererPixbufNew
     
        cellLayoutPackStart  comboPix rendertxt False
        cellLayoutPackStart  comboPix renderpic True
        cellLayoutAddColumnAttribute comboPix renderpic cellPixbuf $ makeColumnIdPixbuf 1
       
    _ <- on comboRenderer edited $ \_treePath newStringValue -> do
        case _treePath of
          [k] -> do
           (ListElement a b) <- listStoreGetValue lststoreManus k
           myMap <- getMap
           let finded = fromJust ( Map.lookup newStringValue myMap  )
           let toStore = ListElement a finded
           listStoreSetValue lststoreManus k toStore
           putStrLn $ "new value: " ++ newStringValue  
   
    fixedPut fixed treeview (10,10)
    widgetSetSizeRequest  treeview 500 100

    containerAdd window fixed
    onDestroy window mainQuit
    windowSetDefaultSize window 600 500
    windowSetPosition window WinPosCenter
    widgetShowAll window
    mainGUI

comboTextModel = do store <- listStoreNew []
                    let column = makeColumnIdString 0 :: ColumnId String String
                    return (store, column)

{-
dependencies :
- base >= 4.7 && < 5
- gtk
- text
- containers
-}
```

[image]