# gtk2Hs : Combo box with text and pictures

Tags: haskell, combobox, gtk2hs

The basic `ComboBox` provided by Gtk can only handle a `String` or a `Pixbuf`

But I wanted a text and a picture nearby on the same row of selection.

I looked for a while how to obtain the result bellow using Haskell and Gtk2Hs.

[image]

Comment: You should clarify what is the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code to obtain the expected result :

```
pic1 <- pixbufNewFromFile "Picture_1.png"
pic2 <- pixbufNewFromFile "Picture_2.png"
pic3 <- pixbufNewFromFile "Picture_3.png"

let lstsecrep = [
                  ("Picture 1",pic1)
                , ("Picture 2",pic2)
                , ("Picture 3",pic3)
                ]

lststorerep <- listStoreNew lstsecrep 

customStoreSetColumn lststorerep (makeColumnIdString 0) fst
customStoreSetColumn lststorerep (makeColumnIdPixbuf 1) snd

combo <- comboBoxNewWithModel lststorerep

rendertxt <- cellRendererTextNew
renderpic <- cellRendererPixbufNew

cellLayoutPackStart  combo rendertxt False
cellLayoutPackStart  combo renderpic True
cellLayoutAddColumnAttribute combo rendertxt cellText $ makeColumnIdString 0
cellLayoutAddColumnAttribute combo renderpic cellPixbuf $ makeColumnIdPixbuf 1
```

Best regards.